# True o False en Javascript

Tags: javascript

tengo una duda respecto a Javascript. Cuando ejecuto la siguiente linea

`console.log(0.1 + 0.1 == 0.2) // true`

Pero cuando ejecuto

`console.log(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3) // false`

A que se debe esto?

Comment: @Aprendiz  Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Cuando pones

```
console.log(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3)
```

Haces el calculo directamente y la respuesta en el calculo de 0.1 + 0.2 para JavaScript
es: 0.30000000000000004
Esto es debido a IEEE 754 Spec

El estándar del IEEE para aritmética en coma flotante (IEEE 754) es la norma o estándar técnico para computación en coma flotante, establecida en 1985 por el Instituto de Ingenieros Eléctricos y Electrónicos

Ese problema de calculo pasa en muchos otros lenguajes de programacion.

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/30711

Para que no tengas problemas en el calculo te recomendaria que lo pasaras a String y luego lo cortaras a tu gusto para hacer el calculo mas preciso, de esta forma:

```js
let n = 0.1 + 0.2;
let sum = n.toString();

let total = sum.substr(0, 3);

console.log(total);
console.log( total == 0.3)
```

Comment: Otra forma de hacer esto es no comparar si dos números en coma flotante, sino calcular la diferencia y verificar que es menor que cierto umbral: este caso: 0.1+0.2 - 0.3 < 0.0001, donde "0.0001" sería el umbral